# Which event to modify GridView data at runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is bound to a data source. I want to modify values of one column while GridView is being displayed.

For e.g. there is column called "NumID" whose value I want to modify at runtime.

Which GridView event shall I use for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks. You should post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: i have added as answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GridView.RowDataBound Event`

This event Occurs when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control.

The RowDataBound event is raised when a data row (represented by a GridViewRow object) is bound to data in the GridView control.

This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as modifying the values of the data bound to the row, whenever this event occurs.